# Linq methods for IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

When working with an `IEnumerable<T>` there are the build-in extension methods from the `System.Linq` namespace such as `Skip`, `Where` and `Select` to work with.

When Microsoft added `IAsyncEnumerable` in C#8 did they also add new Linq methods to support this?

I could of course implement these methods myself, or maybe find some package which does that, but I'd prefer to use a language-standard method if it exists.

Comment: Yes, you can use linq with async enumerables.

Comment: You can use [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) for this

Answer (score 63, accepted):

LINQ for `IAsyncEnumerable` is supported by [`System.Linq.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) which is part of the [reactive extensions for .NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive). The reactive extensions as a whole are split into two larger NuGet packages: [`System.Reactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) and [`System.Interactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/).

While all the packages stayed the same, the extensions now live in the `System.Linq` namespace, not `System.Linq.Async` anymore (thanks Dzmitry Lahoda).

[Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36545)

Comment: The GitHub issue is closed, does that mean it won't be added to the language, and we'll always have to keep using an external package?

Comment: It's closed because it's already available in a different package, which is already available [in NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/). Even LINQ is an "external package" - it's available through NuGet, but you don't realize it because it gets downloaded as a dependency of almost every template

Comment: Update: `System.Linq.Async` appears to be a separate package now: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async

Comment: It appears that it's the extension `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`, which takes the expected `CancellationToken`

Comment: Also note that the return type of  `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` is `ValueTask<T>`, not `Task<T>`

Comment: For anybody getting confused about all the packages mentioned: You want the NuGet Package [`System.Linq.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) (not [`System.Interactive`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/)). The package exposes its async Linq extensions in the namespace 
`System.Linq`.

Answer (score -1):

Since .NET 7, you can use [`.ToBlockingEnumerable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.toblockingenumerable) to convert an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`, which you can then call your LINQ methods off of.

Comment: The question was about Linq support to `IAsyncEnumerable`. Your answer degrade the async collection to a blocking sync cursor which isn’t the best approach to async programming.

Comment: That's fair, depending on which LINQ method someone's trying to call that may be necessary (for example, Sum, Count, ToList, etc. But it's a good thing to caveat. I'm glad the method name has "Blocking" in it!

Comment: To anyone who considers using this, be very sure that you understand what "blocking" means. It's the last way out of a stick situation that should not be taken if it's avoidable.