# AsyncPageable<T> Get first result asynchronously

Tags: c#, async-await

I have `AsyncPageable<T>` and want to get only the first result from the list.

MS docs suggests using `await foreach`

```
// call a service method, which returns AsyncPageable<T>
AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> allSecretProperties = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync();

await foreach (SecretProperties secretProperties in allSecretProperties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(secretProperties.Name);
}
```

Is there any efficient way to get only the first result? Something like `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`?

At the moment I am using this code to get the first result.

```
var enumerator = response.Value.GetResultsAsync().GetAsyncEnumerator();
await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
var result = enumerator.Current;
```

Comment: It's not built specifically to accommodate this use case. I'd probably just have a non-conditional `break` in the `await foreach` rather than digging into the enumerator machinery. Also, of course, you still have to deal with 0 results.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376703/12888024)

Comment: You are doing about as efficient as you will get. Just wrap it in an extension method. pulling a library in for this method is a waste

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `AsyncPageable<T>` implements `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, you can install [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) nuget and use the methods it provides:

```
var result = await allSecretProperties.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` does not contain `FirstOrDefaultAsync` so this doesn't work.

Comment: @DeivydasVoroneckis Did you install the NuGet?

Comment: Beware: Using `System.Linq.Async` with EFCore caused my entire solution to break with Ambiguous references to all my linq `.where` clauses in files that import both `System.Linq` as well as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.  Known issue see: [The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties (IAsyncEnumerable, IQueryable)
#18220](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18220)  AND  [System.Interactive.Async call is ambiguous error when IX-Async is referenced #18124](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18124)

Comment: @rytisk - It is a reasonable comment that can be expected to be relevant to a significant subset of the > 500 users having viewed this SO in the half year its been posted.  Users using `AsyncPageable<T>`, a MS Azure Library, that happen to also use MS EFCore can benefit from the free info in my comment.  It is info I wish I knew before following the advice of this perfectly valid answer you posted.  Re: "Have you read the OP's question?"   - I am avail for chat should you wish to delve into conversation.

Answer (score 6):

Just wrap what you have in an extension method.

```
// hrmmm, im not sure
public static async Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
   await foreach (var item in enumerable)
      return item;
   return default;
}

// This is more efficient 
public static async Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync2<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
   var enumerator = enumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator();
   await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
   return enumerator.Current;
}
```

[Check the IL to them both here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEECsBuWDkQCyZkSOJAGYcA2ZMRAUQA8AXWYgby3JSpAA5kKAPABUAfIgBiASwBOAZ0YB5aQBEApgDMAhgFcANowCCsgJ4A7AMbCRACkYALSbMQBJI2fO1T2gLarpmgCNdVStEVS9ffyDVAEpYdkIiEABORHUAe2lVTXM7RGsAN01pRElGVW9S0zCIv0DguMTiZAB2UvLvAhI2gBMNHX0CAF8WZrGySmQ+EEFRCRl5JTUtPUMTCzArWwcnV3WPWqjg0PCfOujGhOIiktPIzUZMxABeGrOj1QA6AHFVNfdPO8HplrDEuklUnc6o9pJ8ALLpAqqAByqiYbgsoPBrTe9xhnwAwtppFlTIxscQRk0qRxqIgCYgEqMkpxcIg4aDGczEFShkA==)

Comment: More efficient, partly because it's failing to respect async disposal.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah i have been trying to work out if that is going to cause an issue. Also after looking at these 2 code blocks for a while, I think aesthetically I would go with the foreach myself