# How to merge results from GroupBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to filter an `IEnumerable<Product>` by its productId, but I want to have all comments for the products in my result.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<ProductComments> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

For example:
I have 3 Products

Id: 1, Quantity: 10, Comments: 2

Id: 1, Quantity: 20, Comments: 1

Id: 2, Quantity: 5, Comments: 1

What I what now is the follwing result:

Id: 1, Quantity: 30, Comments: 3 (I want the actual objects here, not just the count)

Id: 2, Quantity: 5, Comments: 1

How can I achieve this with LINQ? I think the way to go here is with `GroupBy`.

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried using Linq and `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will group your input as you want to:

```
var grouped = products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductId).Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Key,
            Quantity = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity),
            Comments = x.SelectMany(y => y.Comments)
        });
```

The code uses [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0) to calculate the sum of all quantities and [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) to merge the comment lists into one.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fMNwns

Comment: How can I do it with an IAsyncEnumerable ? SelectMany and SelectManyAwait does not seem to work with those.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376585/linq-methods-for-iasyncenumerable But actually, this is another question. You asked how to do this with a `List<T>`.