# Combine AsyncEnumerable with SelectMany (synchronous?)

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, iasyncenumerable

I try to use an `AsyncEnumerable` that returns a list of items in each yield and try to use `SelectMany` (or `SelectManyAsync`) to retrieve all items.

Working sample:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<...>> source = ...;
await foreach (var list in source)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // Perform some action on item
    }
}
```

But I try to use linq for that like:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<...>> source = ...;
var items = from list in source
            from item in list
            where ...
            select item;
await foreach (var item in items)
{
    ...
}
```

Or in method syntax:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<...>> source = ...;
var items = source
    .SelectMany(static list => list)
    .Where(...);
await foreach (var item in items)
{
    ...
}
```

But I got an error from compiler:

> CS0411: The type arguments for Method 'AsyncEnumerable.SelectMany....)' cannot be inferred from usage.

Is there any way to use the synchronous linq extensions after awaiting the `AsyncEnumerable` or is the working sample the only way of handling such problems?

**EDIT**

What I'm looking for is an extension method like the following one that is supported by linq query syntax:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> SelectMany<TCollection, T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TCollection> self, Func<TCollection, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
    where TCollection : IEnumerable<T>
{
    await foreach (var collection in self)
    {
        foreach (var item in selector(collection))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any extension method like this one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq methods for IAsyncEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376585/linq-methods-for-iasyncenumerable)

Comment: @Roe  Not really. They only provide extensions that have to return a new `IAsyncEnumerable`. In my sample the items are `IEnumerable<>`. And I didn't find any sample for my problem. There are much samples for `SelectMany(async () => await ...)` - but that's not my case.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann youre not making much sense. You cant return `IEnumerable<T>` from `SelectMany` and then expect to asynchronously await over the collection in a `await foreach` loop? `SelectMany` returns `IAsyncEnumerable` because the original collection is `IAsyncEnumerable`. Why would you want to turn an asynchronous enumerable into a synchronous enumerable?

Comment: @KieranDevlin I don't want to turn from `AsyncEnumerable` to `Enumerable`. I've an `AsyncEnumerable` where each item is a list. I try to use linq. There is no loop over `source` until the `await foreach`. My thougth were to add synchronous linq extensions to the `AsyncEnumerable` that doesn't change the asynchrounous behaviour. After that I tried to iterate using `await foreach`.

Comment: @KieranDevlin Please see my edit. I created an extension method that does what I want but is not recognized from linq in query syntax. And please notice that this method performs a synchronous `SelectMany` over an `AsyncEnumerable` and still returns an `AsyncEnumerable`. There is no conversion from `AsyncEnumerable` to Non-Async-`Enumerable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `<PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Async" Version="6.0.1" />`

```
IAsyncEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<string>> source = new[] { new[] { "1", "2" } }.ToAsyncEnumerable();
var result = source.SelectMany(list => list.ToAsyncEnumerable());
await foreach (var s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Wow - thank you very much. `AsAsyncEnumerable()` is what I was looking for.