# Read only first item from IAsyncEnumerable, then cancel

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, iasyncenumerable

When consuming `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, is it possible to just read first item from the stream and then cancel the operation and return it? Something like a `FirstOrDefault` on `IEnumerable<T>`?

Cheers

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376585/linq-methods-for-iasyncenumerable

Comment: FirstOrDefault comes from Linq, as Klaus said, if you would like to use Linq functionality you would need the Linq Async nuget package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8) on using `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. You can get the `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` and use it to get the first item.

```cs
using (var enumerator = myAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()){
    // If MoveNextAsync() returns false, the enumerator is empty.
    var first = await enumerator.MoveNextAsync() ? enumerator.Current : default;
}
```

Comment: You're correct @TheodorZoulias I fixed it now.

Comment: Also need to check the result of `MoveNextAsync`, so probably better to do `var first = await enumerator.MoveNextAsync() ? enumerator.Current : default;`

Comment: That is a good point, edited.

Answer (score 6):

LINQ operators over IAsyncEnumerable are provided through the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package.

```
var discount=await priceStream.FirstOrDefaultAsync(it=>it.Price<cutoff);
```

Be careful though. With an async stream, you don't know whether there are any matching elements until the stream itself closes or you cancel waiting. A matching item may appear in 10 seconds, 1 day or never. That's why you typically need to pass a cancellation token too, so you can stop awaiting after a while:

```
var cts=new CancellationSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var discount=await priceStream.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
    it=>it.Price<cutoff,
    cts.Token);
```

The `System.Linq.Async` operators allow using asynchronous predicates too :

```
var discount=await priceStream.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
    async it => await service.IsGoodOfferAsync(it),
    cts.Token);
```